# how to correctly power the LED of a push button?

Tags: led, resistors, switches, dc-dc-converter, button

So I've got a push button and a switch. Both of them have LEDs inside.
Both of them seem to have LEDs working at 12V. 
But according to the specs of the push button, you could also use 6V.

My question is, wether you have to use a resistor for this LED and if not, how this actually works that the LED can accept different levels of voltage?

Would an LED rated for 12V even lit up when powered with 6V? 
I actually bought a step-up converter to be able to use this LED with my 5V power supply. But now that I've read that you could use 6V, I am asking myself if I even need that step-up converter. What do you think?

The bush button has [these](https://produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/700000-724999/701884-da-01-en-VAND_GESCH__TASTER_16MM3A_250VAC_RING_BL.pdf) specs.
I don't have a data sheet for the switch, but it is called "LA16JS".
Both of them seem to use 12 V for the LED.

[image: right: push button, left: switch]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The datasheet you linked to covers multiple variations of the switch. I count 14 different part numbers. There are multiple voltages and colours.

The note under the table states there is a resistor included in the switch and special voltages can be made to order.

It is probable that the LED will light up on the 12v version if you apply 5v, it will just be dimmer - that may be acceptable.

Comment: No. The 14 models vary by chrome finish color, LED color and SPDT vs DPDT. They all have the same contact and LED voltage.

Comment: @Harper - Ok my mistake it wasn't apparent from that datasheet. - how is the operating voltage specified then? The table implies that there are 5 different versions for the different voltages.

Comment: Well, that part was fairly clear but the rest of the data sheet is *rather terrible* and it makes me doubt the quality of the product.  I expected a 2-axis model number chart for each finish, LED color, throw and LED voltage; my best hunch is there is some electronics in front of the LED proper that allow it to multivoltage.  6-240V is an impressive range, however.

Answer (score 2):

Since they permit both AC and DC power for the LED, I suspect there's some sort of electronics that is  pre-conditioning power for the LED.

I would say, try it.  Apply 6VDC to the LED and see what happens.  If it works,  try applying 6V reverse polarity, which is unlikely to harm a 12V LED.  If it lights in both polarities, that cinches it, there is a conditioning circuit designed to allow multiple voltages.